# Sending bulk mail in background

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have called  thread  in master page on page load and called EMail function and it as follows :

```
Page_load()
{
    CreatingThread();
}

protected void CreatingThread()
{
    Thread tSendMails;
    tSendMails = new System.Threading.Thread(delegate() { EmailQueueSettings(); });
    tSendMails.IsBackground = true;
    tSendMails.Start();
}

protected void EmailQueueSettings()
{
    // Function to get emails which are not sent ;
    // looping it and sending it one by one
    // Function to send mails
    // Updating the status after mail is sent   
}
```

Mails are going but to the same user multiple times mails are sent to them.

Is it possible assign different thread and different mails when a page is loaded next time?

Comment: Re-Read your post and modify

Comment: Why would you put it in the Page_Load of your Master Page, do you want it to try to send these emails every time that anyone calls a page that uses the master page?

Comment: I would use the Visual Studio Debugger to figure out why your sending the email to the same address multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, re-reading your request and comments. I think I misunderstood your request. I was under the assumption you wanted this to work on page load and run in a different thread to what the user was in. But what you want, is something to constantly be running in the back of a web application, correct?

Generally, what I would do is have a console application in the background doing this. But you could do something along the lines of this, in the global.asax `Application_Start` method.

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task beginSendEmailTask = new Task(SendEmailRunningTask);
    beginSendEmailTask.Start();
}

void SendEmailRunningTask()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(300000); // 5minutes
        MailMessage[] emails = GetEmailsToSend();
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(); // Configure this

        foreach (MailMessage email in emails) 
        {
            client.Send(email);
            // Mark email in your database/application as sent.
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to mark the email as sent, where ever you store them. This could be why you are sending them multiple times. It could also be because it is running for every master page load.

Edit: Explanation

---

Website Starts
Task Creates a New Thread
Task enters loop

Task Waits 5 Minutes
GetEmailsToSend() finds first 50 out of 100 emails to send.
Iterates and sends the emails

Task Waits 5 Minutes
GetEmailsToSend() finds next 50 out of 100 emails to send.
Iterates and sends the emails

Task Waits 5 Minutes
GetEmailsToSend() finds no emails

Task Waits 5 Minutes
GetEmailsToSend() finds 2 new emails
Iterates and sends the emails

Comment: Parallel.ForEach() am not getting it.

Comment: to run this function every 5 minutes is it possible in asp.net application?

Comment: What framework are you writing this against? I beleive it came in with .NET4. And yeah, you could do it on a 5 minute loop in a console application or something.

Comment: .net 4.0 ..web  application

Comment: It's definitely in .NET 4, and would be available in a web application. Unless you are running in .NET 4 Client Profile ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: See my re-done answer, think I misunderstood your request initially, was confused by the page_load you had.

Comment: Will this be running always? in Application_End? Dont know much about global.ascx

Comment: Yes, should always be running in the background of your application. Even if nobody requests a page.

Comment: In application_start , it only starts once , if there are like 100 mails to be sent, then how will it work? is there any other  alternative?

Comment: I put in an explanation of flow at the bottom.

Comment: Till all the mails are sent...application won't load?

Comment: No, the loop in SendEmailRunningTask() is constantly running in a background thread in the web application. The application starts just fine.

Comment: Link a pastbin of what you have currently which sends the emails. Or update your question with it at the bottom. Without it, I can't help further.